# Reduce keystrokes in vim

Tags: vim

Below is the snippet of code i am editing in vim.
currently my cursor is at **<cursor>** in insert mode.
I would like to delete the brace(**{**) above the cursor.
What is the best way to accomplish it.

Currently I am doing it as shown below

```
ESC => to go back to escape mode
k   => to move up to previous line
x   => delete {
j   => to move back to the original line
i   => switch back to insert mode to continue my editing


long long modpow(long long a, long long b)                                                             
{                                                                                                                                                                          
    while (b != 1) {  <-- delete                                                                                 
        a = a *<cursor> temp;
```

Can my keystrokes be reduced?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not going to focus on keystroke reduction. Instead I want to focus on how to break this up into smaller mnemonic pieces:

- We are moving the cursor so get out of insert mode via `<esc>`
- Going to be a complicated series of jumps? Consider setting a mark via `mm`
- Move to cursor to brace. Can be done via `[{` (preferred), `?{<cr>`, or slower methods like `k$`
- Delete the brace `x` (preferred), `dl`, or maybe `s` if we are going to replace it with something.
- Move back to last insert position via a jump, `` `^ ``, ``` `` ```, a known mark `` `m ``, `<c-o>`, `g;` (twice), or `gi` to go back to the last insert and put back into insert mode

This give an outline of how to think about each piece and options on how to think about it. Personally I would do the following:

```
<esc>[{x``a
```

Note: This is not the fastest (I should be using `gi` for that), but it is how I think and I find using ``` `` ``` commonly in my workflow to be helpful

For more information see:

```
:h ``
:h x
:h [{
:h ?
:h m
:h s
:h ctrl-o
:h `^
:h g;
:h gi
```

Comment: Bonus points for suggesting gi...shouldn't that be more prominent? That's exactly the sort of thing the question is asking for methinks.

Comment: @Ben perhaps. I am really trying to give options because I find optimizing keystrokes for a specific case such as this to be less useful than learning how to put a few useful motions and jumps together to accomplish a task. I rarely use `gi` as I prefer to stay in normal mode and `gi` tends to lead to more insert centric workflows. For example in this case I see little point to leaving insert mode to delete a brace and go back into insert mode. I would simply continue on in insert mode until I am done then go and delete the brace afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

A few comments first:

- your code sample is a mess of trailing spaces, you have more important things to do than counting keystrokes,
- the commands you listed don't do what you want because the opening brace is not above the cursor at all:

  ```
  long long modpow(long long a, long long b)
  {
      while (b != 1) {
      a = a *| temp;

  <Esc>kxji

  long long modpow(long long a, long long b)
  {
      while b != 1) {
      a = a |* temp;
  ```

As with everything in Vim, there are *many* ways to achieve your goal.

- Using the same strategy as in your example but with the right commands *and a lot of keystrokes*:

  ```
  <Esc>klllllllllxjhhhhhi
  ```
- Using the same strategy but with a lot less keystrokes:

  ```
  <Esc>k$xjT*
  ```
- Using a different strategy:

  ```
  <Esc>?{<CR>xgi
  ```

Note that deleting that opening brace will leave a trailing space so you should probably rethink your "plan" a bit:

```
    <Esc>? {<CR>Dgi
```